# Exact API response language

Tags: api, internationalization, exact-online

While implementing some functionality in my app I noticed the Exact API responds names in English.  However in the Exact software you can define names of several entities in multiple languages. Based on the language settings of my user it would be nice to get the correct translation from Exact.

I found no specific reference in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of the texts returned from Exact Online can have multiple sources:

The Exact Online XML API returns the text in the language of the current user.

The Exact Online REST API returns the text in various languages.

- Generally it will return the text in the language of the current user;
- On [`GLAccounts`](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-financial-glaccounts.html) you can pass in the `CustomDescriptionLanguage` parameter, where you can specify the language you want to receive the description in;
- In some other cases, you will get back the description in the language of the user that created the administration (division) at the time of creation.

  Example for this special case:

  > Your colleague is French and likes to work in EOL with the French user interface language. Your colleague creates a new administration. The language on the administration is set on French. So if you query [`ReportingBalance`](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-financial-reportingbalance.html) for example using your Dutch account, you will receive the description in French. There is no way to circumvent this. This bug has already been reported under case number 01101221. You can use that when you contact Exact Online support about this.